# Select row once if column contains

Tags: sql

I have ran two separate queries, one with all possible entries, and one narrowing those down to a specific item.  I would like to somehow combine (union maybe) the two, but only counting a line once.

this pulls all records

```
select Line_Description
from CSView_INVC_Lines_Master
where Line_Description like '%actuator%' --this is on every single record
```

this is search the same table but for torque

```
select Line_Description
from CSView_INVC_Lines_Master
where Line_Description like '%torque%'
```

I would like to combine both of these and still end up with a total result no more than that of the first query.

so, if I was to join these I would get something like this:

```
Record id      description
1               Actuator
1               Torque
2               Actuator  --because torque is not found on record
3               Actuator
3               Torque
4               Actuator
4               Torque
5               Actuator
6               Actuator
7               Actuator
```

I would like to have something like this instead

```
1              Torque
2              Actuator
3              Torque
4              Torque
5              Actuator
6              Actuator
7              Actuator
```

so instead of returning 10 records, I only get 7 based on the presence of Actuator or Torque

is that easier to work with?

thanks

Comment: I'd restate the problem entirely with abstraction. Abstraction because you've posted what looks some very specific details about your tables and even some customer info. This is a pile of tsql and it's going to be very hard to figure out your problem.

Comment: Pretty much what I think in need to be able to do is find torque, then find all the ones that do not have torque in them then union together and hope for the best. any idea how I could go about doing that?

Comment: It's a bit clearer, but in the end are you looking for a value of some sort? Can you put a `GROUP BY Record id` and `SELECT FIRST(description) as desc`

Comment: nice thinking, then is there a way I could omit the left overs?

Comment: If you have more columns to the right of description you will probably need to omit them first or make sure they are all `FIRST()'d`

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about your question but it seems that what you are asking can be done with

```
Select Line_Description
  From CSView_INVC_Lines_Master
 Where Line_Description = 'Torque' 
    Or Line_Description = 'Actuator'
```

Comment: Ive tried that.  it will still return both tor and act.  because within column it is searching, both actuator and torque can be listed.